# Opencart seo url issue on HTTPS - URL not found error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, centos, opencart-3

We are running opencart shopping site. I am not able to solve seo url issue on https.

SEO url works fine on HTTP url. Getting url not found on HTTPS url.

EG -

```
http:www.example.com/test   [Works]

https:www.example.com/test  [404 error page]
```

When i remove 's' from https and hit enter , product page is displayed but with following url

```
https:www.example.com/index.php?_route_=test
```

We are continously in touch with server team, but they are not able to find exact problem.

We are using AWS server. cent os.

.htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|.twig|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

## END Default opencart htaccess code
```

Comment: Have you changed the url in config file -- define('HTTPS_SERVER', '`http://www.yourdomain.com/`'); to define('HTTPS_SERVER', '`https://www.yourdomain.com/`');

Comment: Is there any difference in the VirtualHost for :80 and :443?  Like `AllowOverride` not the same so the https does not allow htaccess?

Comment: @Dolar Yes.Already changed.